# Find common numbers in Python

Tags: python

I've 2 list

```
a = [1,9] # signifies the start point and end point, ie numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
b = [4,23] # same for this.
```

Now I need to find whether the numbers from `a` intersect with numbers from `b`.

I can do it via making a list of numbers from `a` and `b`,and then intersecting the 2 lists,  but I'm looking for some more pythonic solution.

Is there anything better solution.

My o/p  should be `4,5,6,7,8,9`

Comment: What is wrong with `range(b[0], a[-1] + 1)` (Py 2.X) and `list(range(b[0], a[-1] + 1))` (Py 3.x)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is using intersecting two lists:

```
c = list(set(range(a[0],a[1]+1)) & set(range(b[0],b[1]+1)))

>>> print c
[4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This is using `min` and `max`:

```
>>> c = range(max([a[0],b[0]]), min([a[1],b[1]])+1)
```

Comment: "I can do it via making a list of numbers from a and b,and then intersecting the 2 lists, but I'm looking for some more pythonic solution."

Comment: I think second one is the solution OP is looking for.

Comment: @Tim, I have updated my answer with a second method.

Comment: @sshashank124- Second one is kewl. Thanks.

Comment: Give me 2 minutes please . SO is restricting me to accept it. Cannot accept before 10 mins of posting it.

Answer (score 4):

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]`

The most efficient way is using sets:

`result = set(a).intersection(b)`

Of course you can use a generator (a pythonic way of applying your logic)

`result = (x for x in a if x in b)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `[]` or `None` or sth if sets *do not* inersect. Something like this would be most efficient:

```
def intersect(l1, l2):
    bg = max(l1[0], l2[0])
    end = max(l1[1], l2[1])
    return [bg, end] if bg < end else []
```